# How to create a slippery floor effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple 2D Platform Game, I am having issues with making my character slip and slide on icy ground.

Creating a 2D Physics Material works with Walls but the player doesnt seem to slide when on the ground even with 0 friction, so I'm trying to do it through code and without a Physics Material.

```
// Colliding with ICE
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "ICE") 
    {
        TouchingIce = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "ICE") 
    {
        TouchingIce = true;
    }
}
```

(I know there is not a problem with the detection of an icy ground because I can see in the inspector that the TouchingIce Bool turns true and false as expected.)

Then in Update:

```
if (TouchingIce) {
    iceMovement = true;
} else 
{
    iceMovement = false; 
}
```

And finally in fixedUpdate:

```
if (iceMovement) 
{
    // this is where I'm stuck
}
```

Here is how my movement works when player is Grounded on normal ground in fixedUpdate

```
float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); // moving along horizontal Axis
anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));
if (grounded) 
{
    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
}
```

If you need to see the rest of my code then let me know and I will post the rest.

Comment: You might want to migrate this to the [game development stack exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for that, i didnt actually know there was a particular stack page just for games development, i will make sure i post to there in the future instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that controls your speed is:

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
```

And 100% of your horizontal speed is set by the Horizontal Input Axis.
You need a different way to handle this.

When TouchingIce is true, you have to conserve the velocity from the last update, meaning, if the player was going full speed, reaches ice, and releases the control, they continue at the same speed as the previous update.

Then treat the "move" value as acceleration instead of the actual velocity.

Try this: (pseudocode)

```
if(TouchingIce){
  // Apply input as a force instead of setting velocity directly.
  rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y));
}else{
  // Set Velocity Directly
  rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
}
```

You may find you'll need to add some logic for when the player jumps over ice since you have air steering.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, i have tried adding force but he seems to be walking at normal speed... i understand you said it was just psuedocode but the way you wrote it is how i would have written it for real, appreciate you reply though

Comment: Try reducing the amount of the force you add. Like MaxSpeed*0.05f
That should do it. Also make sure that the rb23D.Velciocity is not being set anywhere else.

Comment: It will work. For the benefit of your understanding, check out this unity Answers thread contrasting using addForce vs velocity:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/619186/addforce-instead-of-modyfing-velocity.html
In most platformers you want set velocity. But when you conserve momentum, like when you're on ice, you probably want to use forces.

Comment: Sorry I have left it a while, i have used your idea and found out that yes the velocity was being set else where and with that correct i do now finally get a sliding motion when the player walks on the ice thanks to using AddForce... but i find the player will suddenly stop a quarter into the slide instead of continuing,  do you know of any other way this could be resolved? My code btw is simply   if (iceMovement && TouchingIce) 
  {
   rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, 0));
    
  }

Comment: I see you are setting your  the y component of your motion to zero. If the player is drifting slowly back up, and does not collide with the ice object, then touchingIce will be false. OR a second collider could also set the touchingIce to false. BTW - if this does answer the original question, please click accept on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with ice is that because its friction is much lower, objects on it retain momentum much better than on normal ground, so you want joystick movement to correlate to a small acceleration, rather than directly to velocity.

I suspect you can keep a variable, oldVelocity, to hold your current velocity.  Then each update, instead of changing your velocity to be equal to your (move * maxSpeed), just add (move * maxSpeed * someSmallFactor) to your oldVelocity.  Adjust someSmallFactor to fit the motion you're trying to emulate.

(of course you'll have to do some other work after this as well, limiting your top velocity, probably adding friction to slow the player down when the joystick is centered, etc.)

Comment: I see your logic here, thank you for your reply, I get what your saying but how would i store my current velocity into a variable and then add to it when needed, the tutorials i have seen only show me the way i have written the code. would it be something like private vector2 curVel; curVel = rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y); .... in fact now that i have written that it looks so wrong with two '=' signs init.